# How does one send an email to 10,000 users in Django?

Tags: django, django-email, django-mailer

My Django application has 10,000 users, all with emails. I would like to send an email message to all of them say once a month. This message could have some pdf attachments.

What I have tried is using an EmailMessage object to send an email to all of them. I add all users' email addresses to the bcc component of this EmailMessage before sending.

```
        recList = []
        for recipient in rec:
            reci = str.strip(str(recipient))
            recList.append(reci)
            message = (form.cleaned_data['subject'], form.cleaned_data['message'], 'emailAdmin@yahoo.com', recList)
        mail = EmailMessage(form.cleaned_data['subject'], form.cleaned_data['message'], 'email_manager@mysite.org', ['email_list@mysite.org'], recList)
        num_attachments = 0
        if form.cleaned_data['attachment'] != None:
            email_attachment = EmailAttachment(
                document_name = form.cleaned_data['attachment'].name,
                email_message = email,
                document = form.cleaned_data['attachment'],
            )
            email_attachment.save()
            mail.attach_file(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + email_attachment.document.name)
        mail.send(fail_silently=False)
```

However, when I send the email, Django complains that "The connection was reset" and does not send. I am assuming that the server connection was closed.

What's an efficient way to send a mass email blast in Django? Would `send_mass_mail()` be more effective?

Comment: Note you forgot to check the recipient.hasSignedUpForEmail flag. Also, less humorously, why do you create 'message' and why is it inside the loop, getting overwritten each time?

Comment: have you tried through http://code.google.com/p/django-mailer/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative suggestion: sign up to a mailing service and use their APIs to maintain your email list and send out mailings. A couple of advantages to this approach:

- They’ll handle any unsubscribe requests for you, so you don’t have to worry about adding exclusion flags to your users who don’t want your emails.
- You’re less likely to get spam-filtered out of your users’ inboxes, or to annoy your hosting provider.

There are API wrappers available for, among others, [MailChimp](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#python) and [Campaign Monitor](http://code.google.com/p/campaign-monitor-api-python/). It should be fairly easy to add in hooks to add new users to the mailing list and (if relevant) remove any users who delete their accounts.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `send_mass_mail` since it won't close the connection every time. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mass-mail)

I would also chunk the messages into groups of about 100-1,000, depending on how powerful your server is. The reason is that you can catch errors in smaller groups for retrying. This also results in a separate email per recipient, which is ideal. BCC'ing thousands of people is not great.

Answer (score 0):

I think, an E-mail BCC header cannot contain 10000 records.

Comment: This is correct. It depends on the email service, but Amazon SES for example allows a maximum of 50 recipients in BCC.